# Rewrite base rule- php

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, base-url

Internal URL: `example.com/abc/xyz/rule.php?price=1&pass=2`
External URL: `example.com/abc/xyz/rule/1/2`

But the css, js files are not coming into effect in the external URL.
My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example.com/abc/
RewriteRule ^rule/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ rule.php?price=$1&pass=$2
```

Comment: Please post the content of your .htaccess

Comment: ORIGINAL URL :http://example.com/abc/xyz/rule.php?price=1&pass=2
REWRITED TO   :http://example.com/abc/xyz/rule/1/2


But the css , js files are not coming into effect in the REWRITED URL.

MY .htaccess file:


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example.com/abc/
RewriteRule ^rule/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ rule.php?price=$1&pass=$2

Comment: Please update the question instead.

Comment: Just a suggestion. This is not so much a PHP question as an Apache question. If you tag it as such, you might get more of a response. (It would also help if you formatted the `.htaccess` file as code.

Answer (score 1):

The “problem” is that relative URLs are resolved by the client and not by the server. And the base URL, the relative URLs are resolved from, is the URL of the current document. And in your case the base URL (path) is `/abc/xyz/rule/1/2` and not `/abc/xyz/rule.php?price=1&pass=2`.

Now you have several ways to solve this:

- Use relative URLs that are correctly resolvable from the actual base URL `/abc/xyz/rule/1/2`
- Use absolute URLs that are independent from the base URL
- Alter the base URL using [HTML’s `BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)