# Friendly url rewriting with php & .htaccess. Difficulties with relative links to css images & js

Tags: php, javascript, css, .htaccess, friendly-url

I've currently an url like that : play.php?place=idplace&event=idevent

I've enabled friendly url this way :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ play.php?place=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /play.php?place=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /play.php?place=$1&event=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /play.php?place=$1&event=$2
```

For just one parameter (the place id there), all is ok. But when it comes two params (place and event) like that mysite/theplace/theevent all my relatives links (css, js and imgs) are not working, my page seems to think it is actually in the theplace/ folder, and non in the root/ one.

Ideas for this issue?

Thanx a lot

Guillaume

Comment: Use absolute paths. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264285

Comment: NB: You can combine your first two rules into...
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /play.php?place=$1
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use paths that are absolute from at least the domain, i.e.

```
/images/myimage.png
```

You may be able to fix this one problem in another way, but it will only become more annoying as your URL rewriting becomes more advanced.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I used images/myimage.png instead of /images/ and it works perfectly now!

Thanks again